# Display only uncategorised item in 1 mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wanting to know if it is possible to convert this code below, so that it only needs 1 query instead of allot more query's? the items table is filled with well over 10k items, and the below way, just takes so long, is there a faster way of displaying the uncategorised item?

```
$CD1=mysql_query("select * FROM items");    
while($C1=mysql_fetch_array($CD1)){
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from category where sub='$C1[sub]'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
        echo "$C1[id]->$C1[sub]<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, and it's called a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - [MySQL JOIN Tutorial with outdated mysql functions](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: 1Rabbit: By using it? You see that the term [`JOIN` links to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)? If you have problems to understand that manual page, use the term `JOIN` to find yourself better suiting descriptions of what a join is on either this website or the internet. -- Goes like this: `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM items AS t1 LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.sub = t1.sub`

Comment: I already looked at join, though when I use this below, it just displays everything but the uncategorised items.    $CD1=mysql_query("SELECT items.sub, category.sub from items,category where items.sub!=category.sub"); 
 #$CD1=mysql_query("SELECT I.ID FROM ITEMS I INNER JOIN CATEGORY C ON I.SUB!=C.SUB");
 while($C1=mysql_fetch_array($CD1)){
 echo "$C1[id]->$C1[sub]<br>";
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use outer join and where clause to filter items with no categories

```
SELECT i.* FROM items i LEFT OUTER JOIN category c ON i.sub = c.id WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You might need to change field names as we do not know the structure of the two tables. In general usage of * is not recommended, use explicit listing of field  names after SELECT

Answer (score 0):

One common way to find rows in one table that don't have corresponding rows in another is with a left join:

```
select id, sub
from items i
     left join category c on i.sub = c.sub
where c.sub is null
```

One note, you should avoid `select *` in anything other than test code.